# Are SMS Spam Opt-in messages required for Third-Party Non-Marketing Texts?

Tags: united-states, tcpa

I have a service where customers can purchase non-marketing SMS Text Messages that will be sent to their friend (customer provides the friend's phone number).

Since these text messages have been purchased and do not have marketing content, but are being sent to a third party (ie. the friend, not the original customer), do they still count as "Spam" and require opt-in verbiage, such as "Data&MsgRatesApply" or "Text STOP to opt out"...or does the purchased and non-marketing nature mean that these spam opting messages are not required?